# Oracle commerce cloud loading Backbone and underscore JS

Tags: oracle, backbone.js, cloud, underscore.js, commerce

I am new to Oracle commerce cloud platform.

What would be the best practice to load backbone and underscore js when working with Oracle commerce platform. It seems the platform does not allow the `<script>` tag.

We would not prefer loading both the library with CDN.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Third party JS files can be uploaded in a folder.
I found my answer here:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97801_01/Cloud.18C/ExtendingCC/html/s2501uploadthirdpartyfiles01.html